# Can you store a Bag of Holding or a Handy Haversack in a Pathfinder Pouch?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Can you store a Bag of Holding or a Handy Haversack in a Pathfinder Pouch? My idea is, that a PC would like to travel light but still have access to their gear.

Answer (score 6):

## Yes

> #### [Extradimensional Spaces](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Extradimensional-Spaces)
>
> A number of spells and magic items utilize extradimensional spaces, such as rope trick, a bag of holding, a handy haversack, and a portable hole. These spells and magic items create a tiny pocket space that does not exist in any dimension. Such items do not function, however, inside another extradimensional space. If placed inside such a space, they cease to function until removed from the extradimensional space. For example, if a bag of holding is brought into a rope trick, the contents of the bag of holding become inaccessible until the bag of holding is taken outside the rope trick. The only exception to this is when a bag of holding and a portable hole interact, forming a rift to the Astral Plane, as noted in their descriptions.

So you can nest bags of holding (and variants of it) without issue, and since the *pouch* functions identically to a bag of holding (as per its description) you can nest with that as well.  You can't remove items from a bag while it's in another bag (just like with *rope trick*) but you can just access the bag by removing it from the bag it's nested in.

Note, however, that the *Pathfinder Pouch*'s weight limit still applies, so some of the larger *bags* will be unavailable unless their weight is somehow reduced (e.g. via the spell *lighten object* or being made of the special material Darkleaf Cloth or both).